# Install libnss3.so in Ubuntu docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am having problem with missing libnss3.so in the docker image. My docker file looks like

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
       unzip \
       wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && echo "progress = dot:giga" | tee /etc/wgetrc \
    && mkdir -p /mnt /opt /data \
    && wget https://github.com/andmarios/duphard/releases/download/v1.0/duphard -O /bin/duphard \
    && chmod +x /bin/duphard
```

Is there a way to install libnss3.so using the docker file? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y \
   unzip \
   wget \
   libnss3 \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& echo "progress = dot:giga" | tee /etc/wgetrc \
&& mkdir -p /mnt /opt /data \
&& wget https://github.com/andmarios/duphard/releases/download/v1.0/duphard -O /bin/duphard \
&& chmod +x /bin/duphard
```

Comment: That's a lot of commands, could you explain why each is needed?